# Nginx configuration for displaying contents in home directory

Tags: nginx

The requirement is to display contents in local user's home directory when you enter /~user.

www.blahblahblah.com/~user

I've created a local user with home directory and configured Nginx like that:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm test.html;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location ~* /\~(.*)/$ {
        root /home/$1/;
    }

    location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
}
```

But I still got 404 not found error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the root and the URI are concatenated to obtain the request filename, so you are asking `nginx` to deliver `root /home/user/~user/`.

The solution is to use a `rewrite ... break` to sanitise the URI. You can extend the regular expression to capture both elements and then use the named captures in a `root` and a `rewrite ... break` statement:

```
location ~* /\~(?<username>\w+)(?<userpath>/.*)$ {
    root /home/$username;
    rewrite ^ $userpath break;
}
```